# Django-rest-framework: how to register route for a ViewSet in another app (same project)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django-rest-frameworks (both tutorial and documentation) indicates to register routes as prefix-ViewSet pairs like so

```
# rapidsms_tut/rapidsms_tut/urls.py 
#> (rapidsms_tut = project name)
#> (rapidsms_tut/rapidsms_tut = main/default app)
from rest_framework import routers
from voting import views

router.register(r'choices', voting.ChoiceViewSet) # choices is the url prefix (i.e. /choices/)
```

However I cannot find a way out of the following error (I'm making modifications to the rapidsms tutorial I've followed, but it doesn't really matter):

```
NameError at /choices
name 'voting' is not defined
/.../rapidsms_tut/rapidsms_tut/urls.py in <module>, line 12
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
rapidsms_tut
   rapidsms_tut
      ...
      urls.py
   voting
      ...
      serializers.py
      models.py # here we have Choice model
      views.py # here we have CHoiceVIewSet ModelViewSet
```

**voting/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Choice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**voting/views.py**

```
from .models import Choice
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import ChoiceSerializer

class ChoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Choice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChoiceSerializer
```

I guess the issue has something to do with directory structure / namespaces. Any clue?

Also, by following Django starter tutorial, I've been taught to have the default app (with settings.py, urls.py etc.) as a sub-folder of *project folder* (e.g. rapidsms_tut as sub-folder of rapidsms_tut).

However I've seen projects around with different apps but with urls.py, settings.py etc **only** in the **root** folder of the project (e.g. in rapidsms_tut and not default app's subfolder). **What's the difference?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not related to importing the module or your dir structure, it's because `voting` is not defined in your code.

```
from voting import views

router.register(r'choices', voting.ChoiceViewSet)
```

You imported the `views` module from `voting`, not `voting` directly. You should change the route registration line to:

```
router.register(r'choices', views.ChoiceViewSet)
```

As for the second question, It's really a matter of preference, Django doesn't enforce you to use either structure. Here's the template I usually use for my projects: https://github.com/jpadilla/django-project-template
The `settings.py` and the main `urls.py`, are in the root project dir. I then make a sub dir called `apps/`, where all of the apps reside